# Правильно ли стоят знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

В "Улиссе" есть длинный промежуток текста без знаков препинания. Неужели они здесь правда не нужны? Мне вот кажется, что необходимы запятые.

– Счет, сэр? – неуверенно переспросила она. – Это значит, семь дней по пинте по два пенса это семь раз по два это шиллинг два пенса да эти три дня по кварте по четыре пенса будет три кварты это выходит шиллинг да там один и два всего два и два, сэр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В "Улиссе" есть и подлиннЕе промежутки без знаков препинания:)

По всем правилам, конечно, знаки нужны. Но это художественное произведение, в котором для реализации авторского замысла возможны отступления от нормы. Скажем, для передачи интонаций и изображения "потока сознания". Да и вообще в разговорной речи предложения не всегда совершенны с точки зрения грамматики, поэтому и о правильностьи пунктуации тут не всегда можно говорить.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае, отсутствие запятых - художественный приём, призванный передать "скороговорку" при подсчёте.